# Problem with action Controller@store not defined in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, controller, laravel-8

I'm still exploring Laravel 8 but I have a problem with my controller's store() method 'not defined.'

> InvalidArgumentException Action PostsController@store not defined.
> (View: D:\Server\htdocs\app\resources\views\posts\create.blade.php)

I believe I have actually defined it and I used a resources route.

**Route**

```php
Route::resource('posts', PostsController::class);
```

**Blade**

```php
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <h1>Create Post</h1>

    {!! Form::open(['action' => 'PostsController@store', 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
    <div class="form-group">
        {{Form::label('title', 'Title')}}
        {{Form::label('title', ['class' => 'form-control','placeholder' =>'Title'])}}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{Form::label('body', 'Body')}}
        {{Form::textarea('body', ['class' => 'form-control','placeholder' =>'Body'])}}
    </div>

    {{Form::submit('Submit',['class' =>'btn btn-primary'])}}
    {!! Form::close() !!}

@endsection
```

**Controller**

```php
class PostsController extends Controller
{
    public function create()
    {
        return view('posts.create');
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'title' => 'required',
            'body' => 'required'
        ]);

        return 143;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using the namespace? `'\App\Http\Controllers\PostsController@store'`

Comment: where should I put that namespace?

Comment: i'm sorry can I know more about the package? Im kinda clueless here

Comment: You should put that namespace in the action. Alternatively, you can use `route('posts.store')` to use the named route.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Go into your `RouteServiceProvider` and set the `$namespace` property to `App\Http\Controllers` if you want there to be a namespace prefix added when generating URLs for actions.

Otherwise you should be referring to your Controllers by their Fully Qualified Class Name (FQCN).

```
['action' => 'App\Http\Controllers\PostsController@store', ...]
```

Comment: I did changed the `$namespace` to `App\Http\Controllers` but I did get another error `htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given `

Comment: How did you solved ? htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can try using a named route in your case since that is a resource `PostsController` you should have the Route name `posts.store`

```
route('posts.store')
```

The instance of incoming request will be automatically injected in your `PostsController@store` definition as the parameter by the Laravel service container.

I had a similar case but I was not using a resource controller. So I had to explicitly define a route for that particular action.

Answer (score 0):

you should use route instead of action in your form. try something like

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'products.store', 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand your where the problem occurs.
You have used.

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => 'PostsController@store', 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
```

which is wrong, instead of this you have to use.

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => 'PostsController@store', 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
```

I hope, your problem will be solved.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

"You need to declare a route so that the action method can find the route you are talking about"

See [this link](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/action-companiescontroller-at-store-not-defined?page=1&replyId=438240)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me to access the store function in the **PostsController**

```
Form::open(['route' => 'posts.store'])
```

and my **route** is

```
Route::resource('posts','PostsController');
```