# Action ProductController@store not defined but it does Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I think the problem is with my routes but I can't figure it out.

routes/web.php:

```
Route::get('/add_product', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'addproduct'])->name('addproduct');

Route::post('/add_product/store', [App\Http\Controllers\ProductController::class, 'store'])->name('store');
```

and that's how its defined in my form:

```
<form role="form" id="quickForm" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{action('ProductController@store')}}" >
```

Comment: you still have to use the FQCN for actions unless you set the `namespace` member variable in your RouteServiceProvider

Comment: would you explain a little more?

Comment: when referring to the action like that you still have to use the FQCN ... there is no route defined with an action pointing to `ProductController@store` but there is one for `App\Http\Controllers\ProductController@store`

Comment: i have to use this `App\Http\Controllers\ProductController@store` in my form action ?

Comment: @lagbox so i have did this and now for some reason its throwing the data into `URL` and not adding into the database

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problem with action Controller@store not defined in Laravel 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63835929/problem-with-action-controllerstore-not-defined-in-laravel-8)

Answer (score 1):

Use this, I do not think there is problem with your routes:

```
Route::get('/add_product', 'HomeController@addproduct')->name('addproduct');
Route::post('/add_product/store', 'ProductController@store')->name('store');
```

and the form:

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('store') }}"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    {{-- START - YOUR FORM DATA --}}
    
    {{--- END - YOUR FORM DATA --}}
</form>
```

Comment: For some reason, it's throwing the data into the URL and not adding it to the database

Comment: I did and i don't know why its doing that.

Comment: Can you include the error message that you get in your question?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use this form with laravel 8 => action="{{action('ProductController@store')}}"
The call with the helper action() it is necessary to call the controller directly =>   [App\Http\Controllers\ProductController::class, 'store']

Comment: Please, give an overview of the problem you are having, some context. Otherwise is very difficult to be able to help you.